Creating and Exiting a Thread that Runs http.server on a Tinter Window
I've been trying to end a thread in python with no result. The main problem  is that when I set an IP like '127.0.0.1' and a port like 8080 as a proxy server on the Tkinter app it runs normally. but when I try to exit it it just freezes the Tkinter app. I haven't tested if the proxy works cause that I can fix later. I'm just trying to develop the exiting functionality of the proxy not the app as a whole.
I'm using a method called threading.Event() to know when it should end on a while loop as it handles the in coming http request with the httpd.handle_request() method.
here is the code:
import tkinter as tk
import http.server
import socketserver
import urllib.request
import threading

# Global stop event to signal the server thread
stop_event = threading.Event()
httpd_instance = None


class ProxyHandler(http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        target_url = self.path
        print(f"Forwarding GET request to: {target_url}")
        try:
            with urllib.request.urlopen(target_url) as response:
                self.send_response(response.status)

                for key, value in response.getheaders():
                    # TODO(martin-montas) Take this get headers functio
                    # and display it in the Text area of the repeaters
                    self.send_header(key, value)
                self.end_headers()
                self.wfile.write(response.read())
        except Exception as e:
            self.send_error(500, f"Error forwarding request: {e}")

    def do_POST(self):
        target_url = self.path
        print(f"Forwarding POST request to: {target_url}")
        try:
            content_length = int(self.headers.get("Content-Length", 0))
            body = self.rfile.read(content_length)

            req = urllib.request.Request(target_url, data=body, method="POST")
            for key in self.headers:
                req.add_header(key, self.headers[key])

            with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as response:
                self.send_response(response.status)
                for key, value in response.getheaders():
                    # TODO(martin-montas) Take this get headers
                    # and display it in the Text area of the repeaters
                    self.send_header(key, value)
                self.end_headers()
                self.wfile.write(response.read())
        except Exception as e:
            self.send_error(500, f"Error forwarding request: {e}")


def run_proxy_server(proxy_ip="127.0.0.1", proxy_port=8080):
    global httpd_instance
    global stop_event
    with socketserver.TCPServer((proxy_ip, proxy_port), ProxyHandler) as httpd:
        httpd_instance = httpd
        print(f"Serving proxy at {proxy_ip}:{proxy_port}")
        try:
            while not stop_event.is_set():
                httpd.handle_request()  # Process one request at a time
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Server stopped: {e}")
        finally:
            httpd_instance = None

def stop_proxy_server():
    global httpd_instance
    global stop_event
    if httpd_instance:
        print("Stopping the proxy server...")
        stop_event.set()  # Signal the thread to stop
        httpd_instance.shutdown()
        httpd_instance = None
        print("[-]")

    else:
        print("Proxy server is not running.")


class SettingsLayout:
    def __init__(self, root) -> None:
        self.root = root
        tk.Label(self.root, text="Proxy IP").grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
        self.proxy_ip_entry = tk.Entry(self.root)
        self.proxy_ip_entry.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

        tk.Label(self.root, text="Proxy port").grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
        self.proxy_port_entry = tk.Entry(self.root)
        self.proxy_port_entry.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

        tk.Button(
            self.root, text="Set Proxy", bg="orange", command=self.button_command
        ).grid(row=4, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

        tk.Button(
            self.root,
            text="Disable Proxy",
            bg="orange",
            command=stop_proxy_server,
        ).grid(row=5, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

    def button_command(self):
        ip = self.proxy_ip_entry.get()
        port = self.proxy_port_entry.get()
        try:
            # Validate port input
            port = int(port)
            print(f"Starting proxy at IP: {ip}, Port: {port}")
            # Run the proxy server in a separate thread
            threading.Thread(
                target=run_proxy_server, args=(ip, port), daemon=True
            ).start()
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid port number. Please enter a valid integer.")

I expected for the proxy to start when I click the start proxy button and end without freezing on the end proxy button with no result.
